# textbox date format excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that allows me to manually enter date in textbox1 which then gets selected in the calendar on the useform. There is a second textbox that allows me to add or subtract dates. The code works perfectly.

Userform Code -

```
Option Explicit 
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean) 
    If IsDate(Me.TextBox1.Value) Then Me.Calendar1.Value = Me.TextBox1.Value 
End Sub 
Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean) 
    Dim dt As Date 
    With Me 
        If IsDate(.TextBox1.Value) Then 
            dt = CDate(.TextBox1.Value) + Val(.TextBox2.Value)
            .TextBox1.Value = dt 
            .Calendar1.Value = dt
        End If 
    End With 
End Sub
```

I would like to manually enter date in textbox1 in a specific format.

The formats will be -

dd

ddmmm

ddmmmyyy

I'm not sure how to write a code that does this.

The idea is to enter date in either of the 3 formats specified above in textbox1, which then gets selected on the calendar on the userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after op's clarification about allowed formats

you could build upon the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim txt As String, dayStr As String, monthStr As String, yearStr As String
    Dim okTxt As Boolean

    txt = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Select Case Len(txt)
        Case 2
            dayStr = txt
            okTxt = okDay(dayStr)
            monthStr = month(Now)
            yearStr = year(Now)
        Case 5
            dayStr = Mid(txt, 3, 3)
            monthStr = Mid(txt, 3, 3)
            okTxt = okDay(Left(txt, 2)) And okMonth(monthStr)
            yearStr = year(Now)
        Case 7
            dayStr = Mid(txt, 3, 3)
            monthStr = Mid(txt, 3, 3)
            yearStr = Mid(txt, 6, 2)
            okTxt = okDay(Left(txt, 2)) And okMonth(monthStr) And okYear(yearStr)
    End Select
    If Not okTxt Then
        MsgBox "Invalid date" _
               & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Date must be input in one of the following formats:" _
               & vbCrLf & vbTab & "dd" _
               & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ddmmm" _
               & vbCrLf & vbTab & "ddmmmyy" _
               & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please try again", vbCritical

        Cancel = True
    Else
        Me.Calendar1.Value = CDate(Left(txt, 2) & " " & monthStr & " " & yearStr)
    End If
End Sub

Function okDay(txt As String) As Boolean
    okDay = CInt(txt) > 0 And CInt(txt) < 31
End Function

Function okMonth(txt As String) As Boolean
    Const months As String = "JANFEBMARAPRMAJJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"
    okMonth = InStr(months, UCase(txt)) > 0
End Function

Function okYear(txt As String) As Boolean
    okYear = CInt(txt) > 0 And CInt(txt) < 200 '<--| set your "limit" years
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong.  

I right clicked on userform and pasted above code.

Now, when I type 25 or 25Jan or 25Jan17, the code does not select 25Jan on the calendar.

What m I doing wrong

Comment: The code works when I enter date as 25Jan or 25Jan17.  br/
When I enter date as 25, gets an error as - Run-time error '13': Type mismatch and code '' okDay = CInt(txt) > 0 And CInt(txt) < 31 " gets hightlighted

Comment: please close this post accepting the answer to your _original_ question and make a new post for new issue. in this latter you'd better post your code attempts and specify what doesn't work and why. thank you!

Comment: as you can see in [this Help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."